# Interpret and use code from a java class

Tags: java, function, class

I would like to call the function (code at bottom) from another class, but I am not sure how to extract the phases below from it.

```
phases[0]
phases[1]
phases[2]
phases[3]
phases[4]
```

this is not my code, I got it from someone else, and I am hoping someone could show me how to get the phases from it and print them to screen.

so far I am calling the function using the following

```
Phase phase = new Phase();
     phase.phasehunt5(??);
```

Code:

```
/// Find time of phases of the moon which surround the current
// date.  Five phases are found, starting and ending with the
// new moons which bound the current lunation.

public static void phasehunt5( double sdate, double[] phases )
    {
    double adate, nt1, nt2;
    RefDouble k1 = new RefDouble();
    RefDouble k2 = new RefDouble();

    adate = sdate - 45;
    nt1 = meanphase(adate, 0.0, k1);
    for (;;)
        {
        adate += synmonth;
        nt2 = meanphase(adate, 0.0, k2);
        if (nt1 <= sdate && nt2 > sdate)
            break;
        nt1 = nt2;
        k1.val = k2.val;
        }
    phases[0] = truephase(k1.val, 0.0);
    phases[1] = truephase(k1.val, 0.25);
    phases[2] = truephase(k1.val, 0.5);
    phases[3] = truephase(k1.val, 0.75);
    phases[4] = truephase(k2.val, 0.0);
    }
```

The whole class can be found in the link below

http://acme.com/resources/classes/Acme/Phase.java

Comment: `phases[0]` (etc.) is not a function or a method. It accesses an array element.

Comment: I would like get get this element from the code shown above

Comment: Sorry to have confused you, I have re-edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Notice that when you call `phasehunt5(...)` *you* pass in the `double` array `phases`.

You already have access to all the values since you provided the array. After calling `phasehunt5` the results will be in the array you provided.

Comment: So far this is what i did `Phase phase = new Phase();
     double[] phases = new double[5];
     DateTime in = new DateTime();
     DateTime someDate = in.toDateTime();
    Phase.phasehunt5(someDate,phases);
     System.out.println(phases[0]);`  However someDate must be a double!! any idea please

Comment: ***Please read the code at the link you provided***.  There is a method `public static double jtime(Date t)` that converts a date to the correct format.  A basic requirement on SO is that you be willing to do your own research.

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the code you provided like you are just supposed to call the code with a date and a `double[]`, and the function will automatically insert the elements into your array.

For example:

```
double[] phases = new double[5];
Phase.phasehunt5(someDate,phases);
```

and then `phases` will be your double array with the five phases.